# C# DLL Added to a Delphi 2007 project

Tags: delphi

We purchased a C# DLL and need to add it to our Delphi 2007 application. I have reviewed a number of methods for adding this using CreateOLEObject but it looks like all users will have to register the DLL on their computer to use the object. Is this true? Is there any way to include the DLL objects without having to register it? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Users don't have to register it. Your installer can do that for them.

Comment: Or there is registration free COM

Comment: Assuming the DLL is even using COM in the first place...

Comment: you can avoid dll registration using virtualization - try turbo studio or boxed app. However, its better to have your installer take care of this.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry for the late reply, I just got back to this project. It turns out the DLL is a standard DLL (not COM or .NET). We have worked with DLL's in the past with basic functions, however this DLL is object based. We are not sure how to integrate it into Delphi. It is a communication library to talk to substation equipment called IEC61850. Does anyone have experience working with this DLL? Thank for all your help.